# Make Column begin in a fixed position on the screen

Tags: flutter, user-interface, dart, frontend

I'm trying to make a column with two children begin at a certain position on the screen. The 2nd child is a dynamic ListView where I do not want the number of children changing the position of the column.

How is this possible?

Comment: Added a SizedBox with hard coded height on top.

Comment: That allows me to move the column around but the children of the ListView still mess up the positioning. How could I make the children of the Listview to be dynamicaly added to the ListView without changing the position of the column itself?

Comment: Does swapping `ListView` with `Column` help?

Don't worry about scrolling in this case, it would work fine :)

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap your `ListView` with **[`Expanded`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html)** widget .

**Example**:

```
Column(
   children: [
     Expanded( //here
       child: ListView.builder(
         itemBuilder: (context, index) => Text('test $index'),
         itemCount: 50, ),
     ),
     Column(
       children: [
         Container(height: 100, color: Colors.yellow),
         OutlinedButton(onPressed: (){}, child: Text('Test'),),
         Text('Another Test')
       ]
     )
   ],
),
```

> I used a **[Listview.builder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView/ListView.builder.html)** because I don't want to do it one by one. Just for the example

You can learn more about **[Expanded widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html)** by watching this [**Official video**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_rnZaagadyo) or by visiting **[flutter.dev](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html)**

Comment: Don't I have to have a Container or a SizedBox with a fixed height for this for me to work? Otherwise the Column's children are positioned straight to the top of the screen.

I want this column to be positioned just above the middle of the screen where the toggle buttons's position cannot be changed and the ListView dynamically renders each child after the next.

I tried your way but I am not getting it to work as expected. I will edit some code to my post.

Comment: Wrap your column with Align(alignment: Alignment.center, child :Column) or  use Positioned widget

Comment: Thanks. I wound up wrapping the column in a Positioned widget and wrapped the ListView with a Container with fixed width/height. I just hope that by implementing this like that will not be mess up the position on the widgets on some devices...